# Выделение памяти под методы класса, если объектов более одного

Tags: c++

Есть некий класс, `сlass A_class;` у него есть свойство `int b;` и метод `void action();` который содержит некий код.

Так вот, что будет если в нескольких местах кода создать объекты этого класса в количестве двух и более например `A_class C; A_class D;` будут созданы полные копии объектов?

Исполняемый код метода `action()` тоже будет хранится дважды? А если память выделять динамически через `new`? А как будет хранится явный конструктор в таких случаях? Будет ли компилятор пытаться оптимизировать код и удалять копии методов?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Функции не хранятся в объектах. Можете в этом сами убедиться, применив оператор `sizeof` к разным классам с одинаковыми полями данных и разным количеством функций. Совершенно не важно как будет создан объект: на стеке или в куче через `new`. Код (тело функции) хранится в одном единственном экземпляре (про `inline` пока не буду говорить).

Нестатическая функция-член (метод) отличается от обычной свободной функции только лишь тем, что неявно имеет дополнительный параметр, ссылающийся на экземпляр объекта. Т.е. на хранение кода функции это никак не влияет.

Конструктор в этом плане не является каким-то особенным и может быть рассмотрен как обычная функция.

Comment: можно пруф если не затруднит?

Comment: @DowJhob на что именно?

Comment: Ну где это описывается в стандарте

Comment: @DowJhob не думаю, что это есть в стандарте. Да и не рекомендовал бы я Вам пока туда лезть вовсе. Выделение некоторого кода в функцию как раз и ставит перед собой цель исключить дублирование. Т.е. выполнять вызов вместо подстановки. Если Вы это осознаёте для обычной (свободной) функции, то должны понять и для функции-члена после прочтения моего ответа. Чуть более сложная ситуация с виртуальными функциями. Обычно для этого в каждом объекте хранится указатель на таблицу виртуальных функций. Но такое поведение тоже не описано в стандарте и отдается на откуп конкретным реализациям.